# AVD properties for Motorola Flipout?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm looking to create AVDs to test my apps on, and i'm trying to figure out the correct settings for a square screen such as the new Motorola Flip Out.  I don't see a wikipedia article for it, or many specs...

On a related note, what about tablets? Actually.. Why aren't there a set of AVD instances with params from popular devices.. or at least a site that lists them for each of the 60+ devices.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The SDK has all of the supported screen sizes, per the Android Compatibility Definition Document: http://source.android.com/compatibility/index.html  Most likely, Google is only going to support those things that are following the CDD and CTS.

Comment: I see that, but it would still be nice to have a repo of AVD 'skins' that have all the parameters set for the device you want to test on..

Answer (score 1):

The Motorola Flipout has a [320x240 screen](http://www.motorola.com/Consumers/XW-EN/Consumer-Products-and-Services/Mobile-Phones/ci.MOTOROLA-FLIPOUT-with-MOTOBLUR-XW-EN.alt).

For the specs of many other phones there are quite a few sites where you could find all the details. For example [phonearena.com](http://www.phonearena.com/) is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of getting another dubious badge for resurrecting old threads, I'll give the semi-official Motorola response... :)

Nearly every Motorola handset is accompanied by an SDK addon that includes a system image and a skin. In a few cases, the addon contains only the skin. Just download the archive and make sure the top-level directory of the archive is in into /addons. After that, you should be able to create new AVDs based on the addon. I find that it's a lot easier to use the GUI AVD Manager than a command line, but both are usable.

Download the addons at http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/tools/

Good luck.